# Yank text between values defined with a global variable in Vim

Tags: vim

The following command yanks the text delimited by ##'s and save it to buffer `a`:

`:?##?;/##/y a`

This looks for the first previous and next occurrences of the delimiter. But I want to generalize this to any delimiter. I was thinking about defining a variable with

`let g:delimiter = "#another_delimiter"`

But I don't know how to access that value to do something like

`:?\=g:delimiter?;/\=g:delimiter/y a`

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this on the command-line, you can insert the value of a variable with `<C-r>=variable`:

```
:?<C-r>=g:delimiter<CR>?,/<C-r>=g:delimiter<CR>/y a
```

If you are doing this in a script, you should use string concatenation instead:

```
execute ":?" . g:delimiter . "?,/" . g.delimiter . "/y a"
```

Comment: yeah that works, tkx!!! I just made a [PR](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime/pull/72) to vim-slime using that info.